# Flask request.args,get not working properly

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I want to use `request.args.get()` and log my data out into the console. So, I want the console to log `{username: "ani", room: "1"}` but it is only printing out `{username: "ani", room: ""}`. Here is my app.py-

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/chat')
def chat():
    username = request.args.get('username')
    room = request.args.get('room')

    if username and room:
        return render_template('chat.html', username=username, room=room)
    else:
        redirect(url_for('home'))


@socketio.on('join_room')
def handle_join_room(data):
    app.logger.info("{} has joined room {}".format(
        data['username'], data['room']))
    join_room(data['room'])
    socketio.emit('join_room_announcement', data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

Here is my chat.html-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Chat App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to room {{ room }}</h1>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your message here" />
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.1.1/socket.io.js"
    integrity="sha512-oFOCo2/3DtjrJG4N27BjSLQWoiBv171sK6a+JiWjp/7agxC2nCUP358AqzxkBUb5jX8g6CYLPdSKQTbC0weCwA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script>
    const socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000/');
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      socket.emit('join_room', {
        username: '{{ username }}',
        room: '{{ id }}',
      });
    });
    socket.on('join_room_announcement', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

It also does this in the terminal saying `ani has joined room` when it should say the room id.

`Welcome to {{ Room {{ room }}` still works in chat.html as it shows me the room id there. Please help. If you need any more information, you can comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script block in HTML you are trying to access room via variable name id as below

```
room: '{{ id }}',
```

But in flask you are setting the value to room. So use below

```
room: '{{ room }}',
```

Above change will address both console.log issue and terminal logging issue.